# Wicket, How can a DropDownChoice select change the options of another DropDownChoice?

Tags: java, wicket, dropdownchoice

Is there something in Wicket to do **two** drop down choices so that the first selection of the first doprdownchoice changes all the options of the second one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the value of the first choice to determine the value of the second one.

I this example I chose to use a `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` that triggers the Ajax update and performs the value change. I'm providing the simple example of populating the second `DropDownChoice` with the Federal States of the country that gets selected in the first one.

Note that I'm using wicket 1.4 in this example, shouldn't be too much different in newer versions though.

```
   // two countries
   final String aut = "AUT";
   final String ger = "GER";

   // their states
   final List<String> autStates = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "V", "T", "S", "W" });
   final List<String> gerStates = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "NRW", "B", "BW" });

   // mapping, you should really get this data from a service or have a constant
   final Map<String, List<String>> countryToState = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(2);
   countryToState.put(aut, autStates);
   countryToState.put(ger, gerStates);

   // the container to send back via ajax
   final WebMarkupContainer cont = new WebMarkupContainer("cont");
   cont.setOutputMarkupId(true);
   add(cont);

   final Model<String> stateModel = new Model<String>();
   final DropDownChoice<String> countries = new DropDownChoice<String>("countries", new Model<String>(), new ArrayList<String>(countryToState.keySet()));
   final DropDownChoice<String> states = new DropDownChoice<String>("states", stateModel, new LoadableDetachableModel<List<String>>() {

        @Override
        protected List<String> load() {
            final String country = countries.getModelObject();
            final List<String> list = countryToState.get(country);

            return list != null ? list : new ArrayList<String>(0);
        }
   });

   countries.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {         
                    // just add the container to see the results
        target.addComponent(cont);
    }

   });

   cont.add(countries);
   cont.add(states);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `DropDownChoice` should update the `Model` second `DropDownChoice` is based on and add second DDC to `AjaxRequestTarget`.

[This constructor](https://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/DropDownChoice.html#DropDownChoice%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.wicket.model.IModel%29) accepts the model and you can store a reference to it in order to be able to change it.

Comment: This one? DropDownChoice(String id,IModel<? extends List<? extends T>> choices) I dont get how it would work, cus for example, the first ddc have 1 , 2 and 3 like options. When i choose 1, in the second ddc i wanna see (for example) 4 , 5,6 options. When i select 2, i want to see  7, 8 ,9. Where will those options be initialized?  Thank you :)

Comment: Well, you just wrote it, although in nature language... in method that handles value change, you should check - it current selected value is 1, set model of other DDC to contain 4 5 6, if 2 - to contain 7 8 9.

Comment: @evilkorona You're welcome. Do not forget to upvote helpful posts and select preferred, if your problem is resolved.

Comment: I could,t. The second DDC don't redraw :(

Comment: I dont know how to do it ><

Comment: I think i found  the answer, but i am really tired to read it now 
http://topriddy.wordpress.com/2012/01/29/intelligent-dropdown-choice-implementation-in-wicket/